# Is it possible to create a "dp" variable in xml?

Tags: android

I want to specify the width/height of a `drawable` in `dp` using a variable

Like:

`<dp name="width">30</dp>`

And when using `width`:

`android:layout_width=width` is like saying `android:layout_width="30dp"`

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create your `dp` value in `dimens.xml` like below:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="width">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And using

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```